# Strange input with fscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read in a text file using fscanf. The input file looks like this:

```
1
Test
0
32.1
```

Everything is read fine except the first integer which gets read as some random value.

My code:

```
while((fgets(string,64,fp) != NULL)){
    fscanf(fp, "%i\n", &tid);
    fscanf(fp, "%s\n", name);
    fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &stat);
    fscanf(fp, "%f\n", &per);
    printf("%d %s %d %f", tid, name, stat, per);
    }
```

Output:

```
11281472 Test 0 32.0999982
```

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Entire function for reference:

```
Task *readData(Task *strt, char *fname){
    #ifdef DEBUG
        fprintf(stderr, "Entered Data import method\n");
    #endif
    char name[30];
    int tid, stat;
    float per;

    FILE *fp;
    fp= fopen(fname, "r");

    if(fgetc(fp) == EOF){
        printf("File is empty");
    }
    else{
    while(!feof(fp)){

        fscanf(fp, "%i\n", &tid);
        fscanf(fp, "%s\n", name);
        fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &stat);
        fscanf(fp, "%f\n", &per);
        printf("%d %s %d %f", tid, name, stat, per);
        strt = AddB(strt, tid, name, stat, per);
        }
    }
    return (strt);
}
```

Comment: The `fgets` before the first `fscanf`, what does that load into `string`?

Comment: You take the `while` loop of and everything works fine!

Comment: The while loop should be there because the input isn't limited to just one block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` does a reading (consuming) of first string in the input file and then first `fscanf` tries to parse "Test" as "%i" format and fails.

You may use [`feof`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/feof.html) as condition in while loop, but (thnx to  John Bode) it is better to check every fscanf and use a flag or `break`.

Every `fscanf` returns a value. As stated in [1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set, EOF shall be returned, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

So, you may want to check the return value of every fscanf to know that something goes (reads) wrong.

UPDATE: 
You should never use fgets/fgetc to check something (without rewinding back with `fseek` or undoing with `ungetc`), because every file read function will CONSUME data from file (current position in file will be incremented). To check errors, just look at return value of usual fscanf/other function you used to parse input.

Comment: I changed the loop condition to !feof(fp) but now the first int in the file still gets read as a random number. I've added the output for reference.

Comment: @Jonas But you do an `fgetc` now instead of an `fgets`. Why??

Comment: The fgetc is just to check if the file isn't empty. I'm rather new to C so my code is expected to be rather dirty.

Comment: No! fgetc does not _just_ check if the file is empty! The "return EOF if the file has no more content" bit is only a side effect, not the main purpose of this function.

Comment: No, he should *not* use `feof` as his loop condition, as it won't return `true` until *after* he attempts to read past EOF, meaning his loop will execute once too often.  He should test against the result of `fscanf` instead.

Comment: I replaced the fgetc with a check that the file exists. It all works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you failed to check for failure of each call, so you can't know what happened.

(I edited this to remove the assertion that %i was invalid, sorry)